# htaccess: differentiate between directory and directory with query parameters

Tags: htaccess, php, apache

I have a little PHP framework like this:

`?page=page-name`

`?page=page-name%slug=slug-name` (in the case of plural list pages)

I'm trying to pretty her up.

---

`/exercises → ?page=exercises` 
`/exercises/exercise-slug → ?page=exercise?slug=exercise-slug`
`/layouts/layout-slug → ?page=module?slug=module-slug` 
(in this case changing the resource name)

I don't have the vocabulary (yet) to describe the problem - but it seems like the second rule is taking over for the first one because it matches both?

`<a href='/exercises'>...`
`<a href='/exercises/exercise-slug'>...`

Here's what I've put together so far (and this work for all the single pages)

```
# turn rewriting on
RewriteEngine On


# /page-name →  ?page=page-name
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ ./index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]


# /projects  →  ?page=projects
# getting tangled up with the next one

# /projects/project-name  →                        ?page=projects&slug=project-slug
RewriteRule ^projects/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ ./index.php?page=project&slug=$1 [NC,L]

# /exercises/exercise-name  →                       ?page=exercise&slug=exercise-slug
RewriteRule ^exercises/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ ./index.php?page=exercise&slug=$1 [NC,L]

# /layouts/layout-name →                         ?page=module&slug=module-slug
RewriteRule ^layouts/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) ./index.php?page=module&slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

I thought that the `$` would tidy up that match - and then the `[L]` would stop it from moving on if if already matched. I also played with the order a bit.

UPDATE

```
# turn rewriting on
RewriteEngine On

# /projects  →  ?page=projects  (layouts, exercises too)d
# getting tangled up with the next one

# /projects/project-name  →             ?page=projects&slug=project-slug
RewriteRule ^projects/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ ?page=project&slug=$1 [NC,L]

# /exercises/exercise-name  →            ?page=exercise&slug=exercise-slug
RewriteRule ^exercises/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ ?page=exercise&slug=$1 [NC,L]

# /layouts/layout-name →              ?page=module&slug=module-slug
RewriteRule ^layouts/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) ?page=module&slug=$1 [NC,L]

# /page-name →                 ?page=page-name
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ ?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: The "L" is indeed suppose to stop it from moving on. Did you check if the browser cache is turned on?

Comment: RE: cache I did all the normal things I do. Command + shirt + R, dev tools, incognito. Leads to `http://portfolio.site:8888/projects/?page=projects`

Comment: For clarity, aren't your examples with the arrows after "I am trying to pretty her up" around the wrong way?  I would expect to see what you have on the left to (->) what you want on the right.

Comment: page-name is currently listed first, I believe that should be a catch all that should be last. I would commit that out while on the sandbox, to test the other three regular expressions. You could use (.*) instead of  ([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) as you would still need to filter the slug=value (somebody could just manually enter the URL with any value)so the pre-check does not give you any real benefit.

Comment: To clarify the ^ marks the beginning of the string and the $ the end ... so I'm seeing example.com/projects/slug where a example.com/projects/slug/reject will not be redirected because the "/" is not part of ([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) and the slug extents all the way to the $ end. ^projects/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/$ would be the match case for example.com/projects/slug/ Noting the ending /.

Comment: I'm reading this RewriteRule ^projects/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ ./index.php?page=project&slug=$1  as going to example.com/projects/index.php?page=project&slug=$1 ??? should that be example.com/?page=project&slug=$1 IE do you need the "." remove?

Comment: RE: example arrows: I'll try and answer that the best I can. The logic in the little router is based on query strings. There's only one index.php type file that includes the page template based on queryparameters past along with the request. Originally I expected to change the "ugly" urls to "pretty urls, but everything I've been reading shows it like this where you redirect the pretty url to the real one behind the scenes.

Comment: RE: order of rules,  I've move the single page rule to the bottom as a catch all. RE: (.*) vs ([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) I'll prefer the shorter one! But switching it causes an internal server error for some reason.

Comment: RE: ./index.php - I originally expected it to just use `?page=page-name` but for some reason tried to add the index? However, removing it seems to work just great. I'll update the post with the latest.

Comment: I'll also note that is says "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource." - but that all the files in there have read access. I'm using MAMP locally. If I add a slash at the end `http://portfolio.site:8888/projects/` at least it doesn't go to `8888/projects/?page=projects` maybe that rings a bell.

Comment: So, `/projects` (and `/exercises`, `/layouts`?) are also physical directories on the file system? If so then that's certainly a problem if you are requesting `/projects` and expecting that to be routed by your first rule, since mod_dir will ultimately append a trailing slash (with a 301 redirect) and the rule will never match (after the redirect). Your original rules are otherwise OK (except you should remove the `./` prefix on the substitution strings - it's superfluous) and there are slight issues/typos(?) with trailing `s`s?

Comment: _Aside:_ You used `?page=page-name%slug=slug-name` and `?page=exercise?slug=exercise-slug` in your examples, which I assume are just typos?

Comment: RE: directories... interesting. So, maybe I'll name them differently and give it a shot.

Comment: RE: typos - I'm pretty sure that's just how they are. Singular page for detail pages. Plural for lists.

RE: folders, I added a preceding underscore to the folders to see, but it seems to be working the same way.